# Intersection of a subgroup with a $p$-Sylow.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $P$ a $p$-Sylow. I have to show that there exists a $g \in G$ such that for $H \leq G$, $ gPg^{-1} \cap H$ is a $p$-Sylow of $H.$

If $H$ is normal is easy, but when I consider the case in which $H$ is not normal I'm stuck. I thought that maybe all the elements in $H$ of order $p^{\alpha}$ must be in som $p$-Sylow but I haven't been able to prove that. Also I tried to prove it using the product fromula but it didn't work at all.

Please help.

Comment: What you have written is not correct. You are probably supposed to show that, for every $H \le G$, there exists $g \in G$ such that $gPg^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ (i.e. $g$ depends on $H$). To do that, start with a Sylow $p$-subgroup $R$ of $H$ and extend it to a Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$. Then $Q = gPg^{-1}$ for some $g$, and $Q \cup H = R$.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I extend it?

Comment: One part of Sylow's Theorem says that any subgroup of a finite group $G$ of order a power of $p$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.